# How to fetch data from a live outputstream with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, fetch-api, outputstream

Live Outputstream Link: https://wunder-provider.herokuapp.com/

I have a live outputstream above that generates random user informations every 3 to 15 seconds. I am creating a React Native application that displays these users on the screen with their informations.

My problem is fetching the data from that outputstream.

When I try the fetch method, it returns this error.

```
  componentWillMount() {
    fetch("https://wunder-provider.herokuapp.com/")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => console.log(JSON.stringify(res)))
  }
```

Error:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at tryCallOne (blob:http://localhost:19001/6cf08556-7310-4c2d-b838-9a8fcadc2be1:3747:14)
    at blob:http://localhost:19001/6cf08556-7310-4c2d-b838-9a8fcadc2be1:3848:17
    at blob:http://localhost:19001/6cf08556-7310-4c2d-b838-9a8fcadc2be1:28372:21
    at _callTimer (blob:http://localhost:19001/6cf08556-7310-4c2d-b838-9a8fcadc2be1:28261:9)
    at _callImmediatesPass (blob:http://localhost:19001/6cf08556-7310-4c2d-b838-9a8fcadc2be1:28297:9)
    at Object.callImmediates (blob:http://localhost:19001/6cf08556-7310-4c2d-b838-9a8fcadc2be1:28516:14)
    at MessageQueue.__callImmediates (blob:http://localhost:19001/6cf08556-7310-4c2d-b838-9a8fcadc2be1:3149:16)
    at blob:http://localhost:19001/6cf08556-7310-4c2d-b838-9a8fcadc2be1:2970:18
    at MessageQueue.__guard (blob:http://localhost:19001/6cf08556-7310-4c2d-b838-9a8fcadc2be1:3132:13)
```

How can I get data from that source and add to my state?

**Solved!**

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      users: []
    };

    const ws = new WebSocket(
      "wss://wunder-provider.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket"
    );

    ws.onopen = () => {
      console.log("Opened.");
    };

    ws.onmessage = msg => {
      if (msg.data.substr(0, 2) === "42") {
        const stringToBeParsed = msg.data.substr(2);
        const obj = JSON.parse(stringToBeParsed);
        this.setState({ users: [...this.state.users, obj[1].results[0]] });
      }
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer posted saying you are trying to parse HTML into JSON is correct. If you open Developer Tools in 'https://wunder-provider.herokuapp.com/' and open the Network tab, you are able to see the requests.

One of those request, https://wunder-provider.herokuapp.com/ has HTML as its response body. This means that when you execute your fetch function to this URL, you are receiving HTML.

Furthermore, if we take a closer look at these requests, there is one in particular that you should be interested in and that is the request to the **wss://wunder-provider.herokuapp.com/** URL. What you can do is create a websocket connection between your React Native application and the server and subscribe to the 'userList' channel.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to parse HTML as JSON. The url you are requesting is serving a HTML page. You can verify that by adding a `console.log(res)`. The output will be HTML.

The `Unexpected token <` error is the `<html>` tag

Comment: So how can I get the data from that page?

Comment: I don't know that particular page. But in its current being you can't.  The page needs to return the json part only

Comment: I don't know either, I couldn't find the solution for hours. Thanks anyway for the answer!